# Cplex cuts only at root

Tags: settings, cplex

Is there an option in CPLEX that allows the addition of cuts only at the root?

I would expect, yes, but I can't find the name of the option.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways:

1. set the node limit to 1 (or 0?) so that CPLEX only work on root node. You can add your cuts, then you relax the node limit, then solve it.
2. When you try to add a cut, do a query first to find out the node count or something like that using the query callback. Only add when the node count is 0 (or 1?)
3. Drop all the integer constraints and turn it into a LP. Then add your cuts, then add the integral constraints back on and solve it.